# Find last word in path and remove brackets with regex using bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have done lots of searching on SO and google.

I am using a regex tester like [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

The test string is `[../../dvl/namespaces/my-namespace-1/notterminating]`

The `regex` I am using is `.*\/([^\/]*)[\[\]']+`.

What I am trying to do (returns empty):

```
$ param="[../../dvl/namespaces/my-namespace-1/notterminating]"
$ echo $param | grep ".*\/([^\/]*)[\[\]']+"
```

I have tried different options with grep by adding different flags like `-o`, `-e`, etc. I have tried `"${param}.*\/([^\/]*)[\[\]']+"`. However, I have been unsuccessful at getting bash to recognize my regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sed`:

```
sed -n "s@.*/\([^]['/]*\).*@\1@p" <<< "$param"
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/6jII2m)

**Details**

- `.*` - matches 0+ chars
- `/` - `/` char
- `\([^]['/]*\)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `]`, `[`, `'` and `/`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars.

This way, the whole string is replaced with the Group 1 value, and only that value remains as `-n` suppresses default line output and `p` prints the result.

Comment: @ChrisBolton `grep -oP "[^]['/]+(?=[^/]*$)" <<< "$param"`? See [demo](https://ideone.com/wwdafZ).

Comment: @Ahmad With `(?=])` you only match the current string. OP pattern implies there can be more chars, `]`, `[` and `'`.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any external tool you can do this in pure bash with `IFS`:

```
IFS='/\[\]' read -ra arr <<< "$param" && echo "${arr[-1]}"
```

```
notterminating
```

---

Otherwise you may use this simple `sed`:

```
sed 's~.*/~~' <<< "${param//[]]}"
```

```
notterminating
```

Or by using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[][/]' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "$param"
```

```
notterminating
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
echo "$param" |sed -r -n 's,.*\/(.*)\],\1,p'
```

output:

```
notterminating
```